# Declaring a variable number of variables before processing of a file

Tags: c, variables, makefile

I am a first year uni student who was recently assigned, as a unit project for uni, an assignment which involved the creation of a program to be named **bake**, written in C, which would implement a small subset of the functionalities provided by the well-known **make**. This **bake** function would read the details of a project's dependancies from a line-orientated textfile and process them as **make** would usually.

[Here](http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS2002/project/) is the link to the project details, if anyone's interested in perusing them.

I've only begun to tackle this project, and my first inclination was to open the bakefile (apt name for the specifications file) and read it through line by line, ignoring comment lines (preceded by a hash '#') and processing non-comment lines.  I will then look for variable definitions in the bakefile. Here stems my first problem:

As we know, **make** supports simple variable definition and substitution, by which common information can be **defined** in a series of variables, which will be later **substituted** back into the target, dependancies or action lines.

Being aware of the fact that a bakefile may have 0 or more variable substitutions, I want to define a local variable for each stated variable substitution in the original bakefile. I've decided to write a separate function, *processFile*, which takes one parameter, the opened file (FILE* bakefile), and processes each line in turn.

However, I don't know how many variables to initialise in which to store the variable definitions given in the bakefile, and I'm not entirely sure how to define a function with a variable number of parameters, which I might use outside of the processFile function to substitute the variables back into the original file, one line at a time.

I was planning the *processFile* function in pseudocode, if it might be of help to anyone looking for my thought process (it's not finished yet):

```
void processFile(FILE* bakefile) {
    for (each line (i) in bakefile) {
        char bakeline[] = line i of bakefile
        if (line i starts with '#' character) continue;
        for (int j in bakeline) {
            char var[1000];
            if (bakeline[j] == '=') {
                for (int k = j; k != '\n'; k++) {
                    store in var the string form of whatever came after the equals ('=') sign
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Obviously if implemented, the above code will only support one variable substitution.

So my questions are:

**How do you declare a variable number of variables, not knowing how many variable definitions exist inside the bakefile?**

**How do you define a function with a variable number of parameters?**

I apologise if this question is excessively wordy; I'm at a loss of where to start.

Comment: Instead of one variable in your program for each variable in the bakefile, you'll want to use some kind of *map* data structure that holds key/value pairs - a hash table, binary tree, or even just list.

Comment: You could use an array dimensioned by the number of variables. So parse the file and figure out how many variables you need, and then declare var[n].

Comment: @Shawn A 2D list sounds like a good idea; would I use a char array to store the variable name-variable definition pairs? I've never initialised a 2D array to hold anything other that ints in C.

Comment: A 2d list? Do you mean 2d array? That would be a pain... you want something more easily growable as new variables are added. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array